# I'm just wondering does PutMethod and void doPut are same?

Tags: http-method, http-put, large-file-upload

There is no clear explanation on the Internet. Please help me. I am suppose to upload a file using put method using spring Mvc. So I am looking for put method example but because each one is writing differently.

Comment: Apache `PutMethod` is the implementation of `doPut`: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PutMethod.html  Are you asking something else?

Comment: So does it mean that if override doPut method it means I am using put method? Well if that is the case then if a use a form with method type put then the corresponding jsp/servlet executes get method but not put method.